# MCH1206 floating point overflow condition

Tags: floating-point-exceptions

IBM OS400 C ILE program

Does anyone know when MCH1206 is issued in a C program?  The C program does not have any error handling defined.

In my environment, whenever there is an overflow, - e.g. result = pow(a,b)

If there is an overflow, result is set to HUGE_VAL, and it continues execution.  In the joblog, i can see this message:
"Floating-point overflow exception occurred in CEESDXPD."

However, in another environment, it stops execution and issuing this message
"Floating point overflow condition detected.
 Application error.  MCH1206 unmonitored by F07RTB at statement 00000038,"

Is there are global handling (e.g. defined in the system level)?  Global handling for maths library?

Thanks